# what is the purpose of using getMenuInflater() in general in android studio?

Tags: android, android-menu, android-optionsmenu, android-contextmenu

What is the exact use of getMenuInflater() in creating options menu in android?

Answer (score 2):

You use it to get a `MenuInflater`. A `MenuInflater` can "inflate" menu resources, converting the XML representation into a tree of `Menu` and `MenuItem` objects. In turn, those objects are used to populate things like the action bar and `Toolbar` widgets.

Answer (score 1):

MenuInflater: [doc link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuInflater)

> This class is used to instantiate menu XML files into Menu objects.
>
> For performance reasons, menu inflation relies heavily on
>   pre-processing of XML files that is done at build time. Therefore, it
>   is not currently possible to use MenuInflater with an XmlPullParser
>   over a plain XML file at runtime; it only works with an XmlPullParser
>   returned from a compiled resource (R. something file.)

What First line mean's in simple words is you can dynamically add/inflate Menu using XML files.

**EXAMPLE of inflating context menu:**

> **style.xml**
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>     <item android:id="@+id/cut"
>         android:title="Cut"
>         app:showAsAction="always" />
>     <item android:id="@+id/copy"
>         android:title="Copy"
>         app:showAsAction="always" />
>     <item android:id="@+id/paste"
>         android:title="Paste"
>         app:showAsAction="always" />
> </menu>
> ```

**Activity Code (Kotlin):**

```
override fun onCreateContextMenu(menu: ContextMenu, v: View, menuInfo: ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo)
        val menuInflater = this.activity!!.menuInflater
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.style, menu)
    }
```

**Result:**

[image: Context menu result]

Answer (score 0):

This class is used to instantiate menu XML files into Menu objects.

For performance reasons, menu inflation relies heavily on pre-processing of XML files that is done at build time. Therefore, it is not currently possible to use MenuInflater with an XmlPullParser over a plain XML file at runtime; it only works with an XmlPullParser returned from a compiled resource (R. something file.)

Comment: Just copy pasting the Doc is not equal to  answering question.